# How to get the index of a column of my jTable?

Tags: java, swing

What happens is I want to get the index of the header of my column of my jTable when I click, I have tried with:

Tabla.getSelectedColumn() But this only devains the index of the column when I click on the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a mouse listener to the table's column header.
In the mouse listener's mouseClicked() method, you can use the `getTableHeader().columnAtPoint()` method to get the index of the clicked column.

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int column = table.getTableHeader().columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        System.out.println("Column index: " + column);
    }
});
```

This will print the index of the clicked column to the console every time a column header is clicked.

Alternatively, you can use Jtable's getSelectedColumn(), which will give you the
index of the selected column.

```
int selectedColumn = table.getSelectedColumn();
```

This will give you the index of the selected column.